# Is there any convention about the form IDs?

Tags: 8, forms

Is there a convention for the form IDs?

I see that core sometimes uses *module_name.form_name* and sometimes *module_name_form_name*.
In my case, I'm using *module_name.form_name*.

Comment: Would you need to put the dot/period in `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` ?

Comment: Can you name atleast one core module where the dot/period gets used?

Comment: The dot looks odd. Rhyme.

Comment: The form id needs to be valid as part of a function name so that the hooks system can react correctly to it.

Comment: @NoSssweat It seems I was tired when I started searching yesterday and I see now I saw yesterday ban.ip_manager (a name of a service) and I confused this with the form id, in this case the form id is ban_ip_form :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drupal core doesn't use the dot in the form IDs because, as the documentation for [`FormInterface::getFormId()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormInterface.php/function/FormInterface%3A%3AgetFormId/8.8.x) says, the form ID should be a unique string that can be a valid PHP function name, since it's used in hook implementation names such as [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.8.x).

The form IDs Drupal core uses follow the `<module name>_<form name>` schema, so you will find form IDs like the following.

- user_admin_settings
- action_admin_manage
- layout_builder_add_block

As long as the form ID is unique, any scheme would work. The convention to prefix an ID with the module name (i.e. the module machine name) has been used from Drupal since many years.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I had a problem reading the code yesterday :-D https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288223/is-there-any-convention-about-the-form-ids/288225#comment359623_288223

Comment: Sometimes it's not that quick to find a function/method whose documentation helps in understanding how Drupal works. :)) I think this question will help new Drupal developers, as most of them would use a generic ID, not an ID that can also be used as part of a function/method name.